# Gnome display scaling doesn't stick

Tags: gnome, high-dpi

I have a high DPI monitor next to a low DPI monitor and want to set the scaling of the high DPI monitor to 200%. However if I set the scaling to 200% in the Gnome settings, nothing happens and when I close the window, it always resets back to 100%. How can I make the settings stick? I also tried to use the gnome tweak tool for fractional settings but that applies to both monitors equally.

I use GNOME Shell 3.26.2 on Arch Linux 4.14.11-1 on X11.

Comment: Per-monitor scaling is only available on Wayland, not on X11 (and it's still experimental so it may not work as you expect it).